# Visual C# - Editing Excel Files

Tags: c#, excel

I've been following a useful article on MSDN about how to search for content in my excel workbook through C#:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e4x1k99a.aspx

The documentation for get_address however suggests that this function should not be used within an application:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.namedrange.get_address(v=vs.80).aspx

"This method supports the Visual Studio Tools for Office infrastructure and is not intended to be used directly from your code."

I'm struggling to find any other paradigms for searching a range which doesn't use get_address in some form or another. Is there a newer more standard way to approaching this problem?

Answer (score 1):

No, that's the function call that you need. The Office documentation has many problems, missing or incorrect details. Just ignore the docs in this case.